# Submitting twitter bootstrapper tabs, with asp.net mvc 3 partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a twitter bootstraper tab, with 3 simples tabs (Caracteristiques, Certificat and Contrats)

the tabs are ajax load with asp.net mvc partialviews, they are tied with modelViews:

the partials views strongly tied to the type ViewModel:

```
    // Load Certificat
    public ActionResult Certificat()
    {
        var modelStaffs = _twitterTabsModel.GetStaffs();

        return PartialView("_Certificat", modelStaffs);
    }

    // load Contrats
    public ActionResult Contrats()
    {
        var modelJoueur = _twitterTabsModel.GetFirstJoueur();

        return PartialView("_Contrats", modelJoueur );
    }
```

the models:

```
public class TwitterTabModel
{
    public ModelJoueur JoueurVM { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ModelStaff> StaffVM { get; set; }
}

public class ModelStaff
{
    public string NomStaff { get; set; }
    public string FonctionStaff { get; set; }
}

public class ModelJoueur
{
    public string NomJoueur { get; set; }
    public string PrenomJoueur { get; set; }
}
```

the Caracteristiques Tab views:

```
@model Controls.Models.ViewModel.TwitterTabModel

<h2>Caracteristiques</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
.... the tabs code ...
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>

}
```

The tabs load fines, what I want to do is to include a submit button on the first razor view tab, it submit all the other models if loaded, however, when I get the post call, all the others models, JoueurVM and StaffVM are empty even though they are loaded. Why is it according to you ?

edit: This is the controller post code, nothing special, just trying to get the twitterTabModel:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Tabs(TwitterTabModel model)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you also include your controller code. specifically the method you are posting to.

Comment: hi Dylan, I edit the question to add the method to get the posting, I just try to get the TwitterTabModel to get the others models from the others tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure a workaround, I pass the input values back as formcollection, instead of the overall model, well it it' s not clean, but well, it works as i can get all the values posted